# How can I checkout commits from a GitHub PR that have been squash-merged into main?

Tags: git, github

At $WORK we use the squash-merge strategy with GitHub, however this makes git blame virtually useless. It only shows the squashed merge commit, which may contain many many changes that do not help.

I cannot change our merge strategy, but I would like to be able to checkout the commits of a merged PR (after it has been squashed onto `main`) *locally*. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure, just fetch the remote branches and checkout whatever commit you need? Assuming they haven't been deleted

Comment: If you did _not_ delete the original branch, you should still be able to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately we also delete remote branches :(

Comment: you are not making it easy on yourselves. You cannot have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @eftshift0 Not true. With GitHub, yes you can. No pull request branch is ever really deleted.

Comment: @andrybak's answer already provided insight in that direction and I upvoted it.

Comment: `we use the squash-merge strategy with GitHub, however this makes git blame virtually useless.` Which is why squash-merge is an utterly stupid strategy. You ought to make an effort into changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `refs/pull/` namespace of refs that [GitHub publishes](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally).

For example:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/42/head
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

or fetch into a local branch:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/42/head:branch_name
git switch branch_name
```

This ref is available even after the pull request is merged.

You can also list all of such refs currently fetched into local repository using [command `git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote):

```
$ git ls-remote origin 'refs/pull/*/head'
3a12346f1d58b3be4742392d9924043a999428a3        refs/pull/1/head
023496783fab0589e7adf59ada4afc5343d7a252        refs/pull/2/head
ee06715454cacde0c5728be56158dadc30da5cac        refs/pull/3/head
```

#### Links

- [Official GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally)
- [Section "Pull Request Refs" in the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/GitHub-Maintaining-a-Project#_pr_refs)
- Description of the same feature in Bitbucket in a [support Q&A](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Difference-of-refs-pull-requests-lt-ID-gt-merge-and-refs-pull/qaq-p/772142).